# Change text/content of video dynamically with ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video template and i want to change the content of video dynamically. Trying to do with ffmpeg but i have no clue how to do that. Can this be done? If yes how it can be done ?

I tried adding text form text file but could not figure out who to add text at some particular time/frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for the problem, its a php solution.

```
function videoConversion($videoId, $batchId){
$font_path = "/var/www/html/james/LeagueGothic-Regular.otf";//path of the fonts
$ffmpeg_path = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";//path of the ffmpeg
$this->input_video = "/home/ec2-user/crmvid/original_videos/sept.mp4";//path of the sample video file
$this->output_video = "/var/www/html/james/final/test.mp4";//path of final output video
/* ---------code for write file -----------*/
$commandFile = '/var/www/html/james/newvideo/command/test.cmd';//path of the command file, where we write commands of video writing.
$fo = fopen($commandFile, "w");
fwrite($fo,"0.7-1.5 [enter] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=$font_path:text='Parineet':fontsize=117:fontcolor=indigo:x=480:y=315',
[leave] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=Cousine-Bold.ttf:text=';\n");
fwrite($fo,"9.5-14.2 [enter] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=$font_path:text='Chauhan':fontsize=56:fontcolor=black:x='300':y=280',
[leave] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=Cousine-Bold.ttf:text=';\n");
fwrite($fo,"14.5-17.8 [enter] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=$font_path:text='Chauhan':fontsize=72:fontcolor=indigo:x='150':y=330',
[leave] drawtext reinit 'fontfile=Cousine-Bold.ttf:text=';\n");
fclose($fo);
chmod($commandFile, 0755);
/* ---------end code for write file -------*/
$p = $commandFile;
shell_exec("$ffmpeg_path -y -i $this->input_video -vf sendcmd=f=$p,drawtext=fontfile=$font_path:text='' -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 $this->output_video");
chmod($this->output_video, 0755);
return $this->output_video;
}
```